# Azure Pipeline Empty artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to create a build pipeline to then deploy on my staging and Live servers.
Am use the below YML to build my pipeline but the generated artifact is empty

```
trigger:
- main

variables:
  uiSource: 'dashboard'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    pushd $(uiSource)
    npm install
    npm run build
    popd
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
    
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  displayName: 'Publish pipeline artifact'
  inputs:
    artifactName: 'myArtifact'
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

I try adding but this just copies everything within the directory. Am only interested in the build that was generate.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: Copy file into artifacts
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

I tried In VS code to run npm build it worked fine and created a build folder.
The result from the build was deployed manually and that work fine. I am just trying to replicate the same here

I have updated it to the below but its now generating an empty zip file

```
    trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - main

  paths:
    include:
    - dashboard/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
  workingDirectory: 'dashboard/'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/FrontEnd.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
    
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  name: 'PublishArtifacts'
  displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'FrontEnd'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: You can provide more specific path for CopyFiles task, for example '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/bin/x64'. Just use full path to folder which you are interested in

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue.
It worked with the copyfile task before archive task.

[image]

Syntax:

```
# Copy files v2
# Copy files from a source folder to a target folder using patterns matching file paths (not folder paths).
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    #SourceFolder: # string. Source Folder. 
    Contents: '**' # string. Required. Contents. Default: **.
    TargetFolder: # string. Required. Target Folder.
```

Answer (score -1):

After `'npm install and build'`, add copy task and change SourceFolder name. If it named 'build' in local, it should be `SourceFolder: 'build'`

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to Artifact Staging Directory'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'public'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true
```

I usually use zip and PublishBuildArtifacts@1.

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Zip Artifact Staging Directory to yourproject.zip'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/yourproject.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Build Artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/yourproject.zip'
    ArtifactName: 'your-project'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Thanks, however this is now empty. the zip generate is empty. I have added the yml above

Comment: Add copyfiles2 task before the archive task. Npm install, copy, archive, publish.